# Can't be exported from this NgModule, as it must be imported first ==> even though it's imported

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to add an angular-material [multi-select component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/6xvsft?file=src%2Fexample%2Fselect-multiple-example.html,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts).

I've added and modified 6 files and I still get these errors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why this is not compiling?

Answer (score 0):

This angular error is about  the `imports:[]` from your `@Ngmodule` not containing the class you are exporting.

The javascript import of the class from another file... (which you have highlighted...) `import { SelectMultipleExampleModule } from ...` is not what is meintioned in the error...

To resolve, change your @Ngmodule import like this:

```
@Ngmodule({
  imports: [SelectMultipleExampleModule],
  exports: [SelectMultipleExampleModule],
  ...
```